# Await fetch returns 2 arrays and data can't be used

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm working on a full-stack project using Express in back-end and react in front-end. Now the problem is with a specific component. It is supposed to fetch the results of a database query from /api/blogposts. But then it goes wrong.

here's my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Blogposts.css';
import SingleBpost from '../SingleBpost/SingleBpost.js';

class Blogposts extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            receivedPosts: []
        };
    }
    async getBpostsFromServer() {
            const response = await fetch("/api/blogposts");
            let myPosts = await response.json();
            this.setState({receivedPosts: myPosts});
        }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.getBpostsFromServer();
    }
    render() {
        console.log(this.state.receivedPosts);
        return(
            <div id="Blogposts">
            <SingleBpost title="Test" date="18/12/2021" author="Kepos Team" body="Hello, this is a test for the blogposts!" />
            </div>
        );
    }
}


export default Blogposts;
```

There is only one console.log: console.log(this.state.receivedPosts); but the console gives me two results: first it prints an array that I don't recognize, then it prints the array that I need. (here's a screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sz9rt.jpg).

But when I try to feed the data from this.state.receivedPosts into my  component like this:

```
<SingleBpost title={this.state.receivedPosts[0].title} (etc etc) />
```

It doesn't work (my screen sctually turns blank).

Does anyone have any idea as to what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks for any help!

Comment: First console log output is your default state which you in constructor. once the data is fetched it updated state with fetched data.

Comment: You need to check if receivedPosts are present or not before accessing them

Answer (score 0):

You can use `&&` which will protect you from that case

```
render() {
        return (
            this.state.receivedPosts && this.state.receivedPosts.length
            <div id="Blogposts">
            <SingleBpost title="Test" date="18/12/2021" author="Kepos Team" body="Hello, this is a test for the blogposts!" />
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Or handling it via ternary operator:

```
 render() {
            return (
                this.state.receivedPosts && this.state.receivedPosts.length ?
                <div id="Blogposts">
                <SingleBpost title="Test" date="18/12/2021" author="Kepos Team" body="Hello, this is a test for the blogposts!" />
                </div> : null
            );
        }
```

Comment: This will still end up with error as `Boolean([])`  will result in true only, you need to check length though